# shift col names by right without compromising the values

Tags: r, error-handling, multiple-columns, sample, names

I have a data that looks like:
[image]

I want to shift the ENSG0000000223972.5 to right by one without compromising the values.
So that ENSG0000223972.5 should take place of ENSGOOOO227232.5 and so on. shift the col names by 1 position to right without changing the values. So eventually row1col1 name would be empty.
I tried to do this:

```
names(genecount) = names(genecount)[-1]
```

Comment: It's not hard to shift column names, but looking at the picture of output (_please_ use real data, pics are not good for several reasons) it looks as if it was read in incorrectly. Consider checking with your `read.*` function to see if adding `row.names=` helps.

Comment: But your command cannot work, because the length on the LHS is different than the length on the RHS.

Comment: Images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Reproducibility: (sample data, code, expected output) https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility with base R is to first create an empty column (i.e., `new`), so that we can shift the column names to the right. Then, you want to use the names from the first column to the last column (minus the `new` column) to overwrite the column names. However, I also added in a name for the first column called `name`.

```
df$new <- ""
names(df)[1:ncol(df)] <- c("name", names(df)[1:ncol(df) - 1])
```

Possible `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(new = NA) %>%
  column_to_rownames(names(df)[1]) %>%
  rename_all(~names(df)) %>%
  rownames_to_column("name")
```

**Output**

```
                      name ENSGO00000223972.5 ENSG00000227232.5 ENSGO0000278267.1 ENSGO0000243485.5
1 GTEX-1117F-0226-SM-5GZZ7                  0               187                 0                  
2 GTEX-1117F-0426-SM-5EGHI                  0               109                 0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ENSGO00000223972.5 = c("GTEX-1117F-0226-SM-5GZZ7", "GTEX-1117F-0426-SM-5EGHI"),
                     ENSG00000227232.5 = c(0, 0),
                     ENSGO0000278267.1 = c(187, 109), ENSGO0000243485.5 = c(0, 0)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Yes, I am able to do it.